# X is the major conference in our domain next to / beside / alongside Y

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

X is the name of a conference. Y is the name of a conference.

I wonder which form(s) are correct amongst the following:

- X is the major conference in our domain *next to* Y.
- X is the major conference in our domain *beside* Y.
- X is the major conference in our domain *alongside* Y.

I would also be interested in alternative formulations (if possible, without significantly altering the sentence structure).

The intended meaning is as follows: there exist many conferences in our domain, X and Y are the two major conferences, and X is on a par with Y.

Answer (score 1):

If X and Y really are equal, why not say so?

```
X and Y are the major conferences in our domain
```

If they are not equal and X is the more imoortant, it would be better to say

```
X is the major conference in our domain, followed by Y
```

If the difference between X and Y is small, yiu could say "closely followed by"

Comment: Thanks, `X and Y are the major conferences in our domain` is nice but I would prefer to have `Y` mentioned somewhere around the end of the sentence.